# Why TL071 doesn't act as a comparator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, signal, comparator, square

I am trying to obtain a square wave using a comparator and a sine wave signal. Sine wave has adjustable peak to peak amplitude with +10/-10 volts as limits.

TL071 runs with +12/-12 volts. Sine wave has a frequency of 16 kHz

I connected the sine wave to the non-inverting input and ground to the inverting input. I can’t get any output signal, output is always 0 volts.

[image: Comparator and sine wave]

*Lines going up are attached to the virtual oscilloscope.

Comment: in the simulation, or in real life?

Comment: Are the supply voltages actually there?

Comment: Both in simulation and real life. Yes supply voltages are really there, since there are 2 other opAmps I made rail and connected them all to it.

Comment: Something shorts the opmp output to ground.

Answer (score -4):

Grounding the negative input will kill the output. Connect the negative input directly to the output, feed the signal to the positive input, then you form a non-inverting buffer.

Comment: He doesn't want a buffer, he wants a comparator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).